# How to remove a system CSS file in a Drupal 8 theme?

Tags: drupal

I am trying to remove Drupal CSS files (such as ajax-progress.module.css) from my custom theme YML. Here is what I tried:

```
name: Mercante
type: theme
description: Tema para o site Mercante.co
core: 8.x
stylesheets-remove:
  - core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      theme:
        css/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
```

Drupal's documentation about that is scarce at best...

Answer (score 2):

With Drupal 8.5 you need a lot more. This removes everything:

`libraries-override:
  system/base: false
  system/admin: false
  system/maintenance: false
  system/drupal.system: false
  system/drupal.system.modules: false
  system/diff: false
  system/drupal.system.date: false
  contextual/drupal.contextual-links: false
  quickedit/quickedit: false
  views/views.module: false`

Obviously disabling modules you don't use like quickedit will help too, then you won't need to list them here.

Answer (score 1):

This is for people who have **'stable'** in the css path!
I was dealing with this long time but only this solution worked to me:

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - '@stable/css/system/components/align.module.css'
```

But then I had to perform:

```
http://yourwebsite.local/core/rebuild.php
```

even when my cache is disabled everywhere using settings.local.php method as recommended.

I hope it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use libraries-override to remove the library associated with the all CSS components in mytheme.info.yml:

```
   libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

Refer this link : 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178406/stylesheets-remove-in-info-yml-file-doesnt-work

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198315/removing-all-stable-themes-css-from-a-drupal-8-custom-theme

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the leading slash /

```
stylesheets-remove:
  - /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css
```